# Нужно чтобы строки расположились в двумерном массиве в алфавитном порядке по первому символу строки

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, двумерный-массив

Задание следующее:
В двумерный массив **(не вектор)** вводятся символы(как слова, но у каждого символа свой индекс). В массив указателей нужно занести соответствующие ссылки на строки(в двумерном массиве не более 10 строк, в каждой из которых не более 80 символов). Потом нужно отсортировать строки в алфавитном порядке по первому элементу, то есть в `cBuffer[1][]` первый символ ближе к символу 'А'.

'#' - разделяет строки, '*' - конец ввода, для простоты чтения, в цикле while вроде проблемы все решил как смог. Так же не до конца понимаю, как здесь применять массив указателей, поэтому думаю, что не правильно им пользуюсь

```
#include <intrin.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl; using std::string;

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

#define STOP_SYMBOL '#'
#define STOP_STRING '*'
#define M 80
#define N 10

    char cBuffer[N][M];


    char* cPointersbegin[N]; // указатель на первый символ строки
    char* cPointersend[N]; // указатель на последний символ строки



    //Цикл ввода строк:
    bool checkstring = false; // проверка на завершение ввода
    bool checksymbol = false; // проверка на конец строки
    int i = 0;
    int countstrings = 0;
    while (i < N) {
        int j = 0;
        int countsym = 0;
        checksymbol = false;
        if (checkstring == false) {
            for (; j < M; ++j) {
                if (checksymbol == false && checkstring == false) {
                    cBuffer[i][j] = getchar();


                    if (cBuffer[i][j] == STOP_STRING) {
                        checkstring = true;
                        cBuffer[i][j] = ' ';

                    }
                    else if (cBuffer[i][j] == STOP_SYMBOL) {
                        checksymbol = true;
                        cBuffer[i][j] = ' ';

                    }
                    countsym = j;
                }
                else {
                    cBuffer[i][j] = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (; j < M; ++j) {
                cBuffer[i][j] = NULL;
            }
        }



        countstrings = i;
        cPointersbegin[i] = &cBuffer[i][0];
        cPointersend[i] = &cBuffer[i][countsym];
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Ввод строк завершен...\n\n";
    // сортировка
    for (int k = 0; k < N - 1; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            if (static_cast<int>(*cPointersbegin[k]) > static_cast<int>(*cPointersbegin[k + 1])) {
                char min = cBuffer[k + 1][i];
                cBuffer[k + 1][i] = cBuffer[k][i];
                cBuffer[k][i] = min;
            }
        }
    }
    // вывод 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
            cout << cBuffer[i][j];
        } cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Проблема следующая**:

**Ввод**: `Bello#Hello#Cello#Allow*`
**Вывод**:

```
 Ввод строк завершен...

Bello
Cello
Aello
llow





H
```

**Ожидаемый вывод**:

```
Aello
Bello
Cello
Hello
```

A B C H в алфавитном порядке

Comment: Добавьте ввод, ожидаемый вывод и фактический вывод

Comment: @Yami добавил к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас программа считает что вы вводите 10 строк, из-за чего добавляются еще 6 которые, как я понимаю, сортировать не нужно. Также сама сортировка работает не совсем понятным образом. Вот пример сортировки по первому символу пузырьком

```
// сортировка
for (int i = countstrings; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if(cBuffer[j][0] > cBuffer[j + 1][0]) {
            for(int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
                std::swap(cBuffer[j][k], cBuffer[j + 1][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```